# Python:how to get unique values over 2 different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df
    idA  idB  yA  yB
0   3     2   0   1
1   0     1   0   0
2   0     4   0   1
3   0     2   0   1
4   0     3   0   0
```

I would like to have a unique `y` for each `id`. So

```
df
    id   y
0    0   0
1    1   0
2    2   1
3    3   3
4    4   1
```

Comment: Why does `id == 2` end up with `y == 1`, not `y == 0`, whereas `id == 0` and `1` both ended up with `y == 0`? And where did `y == 3` come from, since the only values in columns `yA` and `yB` are 0 and 1? It seems there are omitted rows in your example's input, and the logic is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

First create new DataFrame by flatten columns selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by `id` column:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'id':df.iloc[:,:2].values.ravel(), 
                     'y': df.iloc[:,2:4].values.ravel()})
        .sort_values('id')
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df2)
   id  y
0   0  0
1   1  0
2   2  1
3   3  0
4   4  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.DataFrame({'id':df.iloc[:,:2].values.ravel(), 
                    'y': df.iloc[:,2:4].values.ravel()}))

   id  y
0   3  0
1   2  1
2   0  0
3   1  0
4   0  0
5   4  1
6   0  0
7   2  1
8   0  0
9   3  0
```